# FSL Service Appointment Schedule more than 2 records in dependent mode (Same Start)

Tags: field-service-lightning, fsl

I have following **requirement**:
"As an dispatcher agent I want to schedule up to 3 or more Service Appoitments for the same time to different Service Resources."

In Field Service Lightning we have a feature to create Scheduling Dependencies Between Service Appointments. **But the limitation is 2.**

*"You can schedule Same Start dependencies for up to two appointments in a dependency group."*

I have made a POC to confirm that and this is a screen with following error:
[image]

The limitations are described below:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pfs_complex_work_considerations.htm&type=5

**My question is** if there is any other possibility (feature / workaround) to achieve the expected result as described in requirement?

I will be grateful for advises. Thanks!

Useful documentation:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pfs_complex_work.htm&type=5
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pfs_complex_work_setup.htm&type=5
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pfs_complex_work_create.htm&type=5

Comment: Did you ever get an answer or figured it out yourself? I had the same question in regard to my thesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New FSL release bring possibilities to create dependency up to 5 SA when ESO is enabled.